# How to Change NSDate Format

Tags: iphone, objective-c, timezone, nsdate, date-format

I am trying to change format of a date in objective c. I have a `NSDate` in the following format..

```
2012.03.14 AD at 03:22:13 PDT
```

This code working fine.

```
 NSDateFormatter* df_utc = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[df_utc setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"PST"]];  
[df_utc setDateFormat:@"yyyy.MM.dd G 'at' HH:mm:ss zzz"];
```

i want to convert to

`03/14/2012 5:12:38 IST` this format.. I tried something like this

```
 NSDateFormatter* df_utc = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[df_utc setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"PST"]];
[df_utc setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss z"];
[df_utc stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
```

But it's returning `NULL` values, Anyone help me to figure out.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: What exactly is not working? You could call then `[df_utc stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]`

Comment: Can we see more of where this section of code is? I presume you're storing the returned string in a variable.

Comment: I just used your exact code sans the autorelease (I used ARC) and time zone (date format string: @"MM/dd/yyyy"). The string returned was valid and NSLog verified.

Comment: @BrianPalma i want date format string: @"MM/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss z" like this.

Comment: @Suresh.D Which line or variable is NULL? As @BrianPalma said `[df_utc stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];` gives you back a valid string, also without using ARC. How do you add the returned string to logging or to a variable?

Answer (score 2):

So in your actual code, you probably don't use `[NSDate date]` to create the date, but another data? Have you checked, that your date is NOT `nil`, when putting it into the formatter? Have you tried if your formatter is working just with `[NSDate date]`? Also your `zone` variable could be the problem. Is it filled correctly?

Is this your actual code? If not pls show us. And you can always use the debuger, to check line by line, if some variables are `nil`or not the value, you expected.

Comment: My first though would be that zone is invalid as well if this doesn't even work with [NSDate date].